# Error moving wordpress into sub domain

Tags: php, wordpress

Moved WordPress into a sub directory and got this error:

> **Fatal error**: Function name must be a string in
>   /home/content/61/11855861/html/wordpress/index.php on line 17

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require $wordpress ('/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Comment: did you change the path in wp-option table in db?

Comment: This: `$wordpress ('/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');` doesn't seem to be making sense, and I can find it nowhere else in the code base. Are you sure you didn't accidentally paste the `$wordpress` in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error lies on this line

```
require $wordpress ('/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

That's not the default line in WordPress' index.php script. The `$wordpress` variable is undefined and even if it was defined you are not concatenating it correctly. The default one is

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this link:

[Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Also:

[Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

**Extra Note**: If you have problem with **permalinks** you should return permalink settings to `default`, then return it again to your own choise